# Relation between norms and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

I'm trying to show that for $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^N$ and $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times N}$ that
$$
\|\mathbf{Ax}\|_2^2-\|\mathbf{x}\|_2^2=\langle(\mathbf{A}^\ast \mathbf{A}-\mathbf{I})\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}\rangle.$$

I understand why this is true for the real setting, but I'm stuck with the complex setting.

Comment: By definition, $\lVert \mathbf{y}\rVert^2 = \langle \mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}\rangle$. Don't think about the specific definition of the inner product, just use its properties and the properties of the adjoint; they'll do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

$\|Ax\|_2^2 = \langle Ax, Ax \rangle = \langle A^* A x, x\rangle$

$\|x\|_2^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$

Therefore, $\|Ax\|_2^2 - \|x\|_2^2 = \langle A^* A x, x\rangle - \langle x,x\rangle$
which leads to the desired expression.